How to sum values in Excel sheet and save value to new row
I have some code in Python which, very briefly explained:

Reads CSV files and converts them to XSLX files, which are paired by date-suffixes. So, there are two files for each date, one called "FLIS YYYY-MM-DD" and one called "SEI2 YYYY-MM-DD"

The pairs of XLSX files are compared to find any differences between the pairs.

Data is contained in 5 columns. An example from a pair of files, after conversion etc., could look like this

File 1:


File2:




The code checks if there are any differences between the files. It checks values in row 3 in file 1 against row 4 in file 2 - which is for some reason just the way I could get it to work. If any differences are found between the files, the code tells me so.

In the example above, the values in D3 + D4 in file 1 add up to the value in D4 in file 2. I need the code to add the values in row 3, with the values in row 4, as it is the sum of these values (A3 + A4, B3 + B4 etc.) that is important to me.


The current code looks like this:
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
from datetime import date
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

# Path
directory = "#The path of the files"

# Expression to find date suffix in CSV for reading files
pattern = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'

# Dict of ID's
number_to_name = {
    # List removed to shorten post
}

# Function for translating ID
def translate_number(number):
    return number_to_name.get(number, f"Unknown_{number}")

# Function to compare pairs of Excel files
def compare_excel_files(file1, file2, skiprows1=None, skiprows2=None):
    # Read the Excel files
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, skiprows=skiprows1)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, skiprows=skiprows2)

    # Compare their dataframes
    differences = df1.compare(df2)

    if not differences.empty:
        # Display which file pairs contain differences
        filename1 = os.path.basename(file1)
        filename2 = os.path.basename(file2)
        print(f"Differences found between {filename1} and {filename2} :")
        print(differences)
        print()  # Add newline between each for clarity
        return True
    return False

# Function to find missing IDs in an Excel sheet
def find_missing_IDs(file_path):
    # Read the Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

    # Find unique ID names in the Excel sheet
    present_IDs = set(df.iloc[-1, :])

    # Find missing IDs
    missing_IDs = set(number_to_name.values()) - present_IDs

    return missing_IDs

# Flag to track if there are differences in the files
differences_found = False

# Go through each file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        # Find date from CSV filename
        match = re.search(pattern, filename)
        if match:
            date_suffix = match.group(1)
        # Skip files if filename does not match the desired format
        else:
            print(f"Skipping file {filename} as it does not have a valid date suffix.")
            continue

        # Read data from CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, filename), header=None)

        # Split data in the first column out to the necessary number of columns
        max_commas = df[0].str.split(',').transform(len).max()
        df[[f'name_{x}' for x in range(max_commas)]] = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)

        # Remove the original unnamed column
        df.drop(0, axis=1, inplace=True)

        # Remove last column (name_0 - column only shows report time)
        df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='name_0')))]

        # Find SOR number
        ids_row = df.iloc[0]

        # Translate SOR number to ID name
        translated_ids_row = ids_row.apply(translate_number)

        # Create new dataframe with row for ID names
        translated_df = pd.DataFrame([translated_ids_row.tolist()], columns=df.columns)

        # Insert new dataframe onto the original dataframe (new row at the bottom with ID name)
        df = pd.concat([df, translated_df], ignore_index=True)

        # Save the new dataframe as an Excel file
        try:
            # Pull filename without path name
            filename_only = os.path.basename(filename)
            output_name = f"{filename_only.split('_')[2].split('-')[0]} {date_suffix}.xlsx"
            output_path = os.path.join(directory, output_name)
            df.to_excel(output_path, index=None)

            # Check if there is a corresponding file to compare with (date pair), and if there are differences, set differences_found to True
            if "FLIS" in filename:
                sei2_filename = f"SEI2 {date_suffix}.xlsx"
                sei2_file = os.path.join(directory, sei2_filename)
                if os.path.exists(sei2_file):
                    if compare_excel_files(output_path, sei2_file, skiprows1=[2], skiprows2=[3]):
                        differences_found = True

            elif "SEI2" in filename:
                flis_filename = f"FLIS {date_suffix}.xlsx"
                flis_file = os.path.join(directory, flis_filename)
                if os.path.exists(flis_file):
                    if compare_excel_files(output_path, flis_file, skiprows1=[3], skiprows2=[2]):
                        differences_found = True

        # Print message if there is an error when trying to save
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"There was an error when I tried to save: {e}")

# If there are no differences in date-paired files
if not differences_found:
    print("No differences found in any of the files.")
    print()

# Function to ask the user to show missing IDs
def ask_show_missing_IDs():
    while True:
        answer = input("Would you like a list of which IDs did not appear in the data on the different days? (Yes/No): ").strip().lower()
        print()
        if answer in ["yes", "no"]:
            return answer == "yes"
        else:
            print("Please answer with 'Yes' or 'No'.")

# Function to extract the date from the filename
def extract_date(filename):
    # Remove any path and file type name, and then split by space and '-' to get the date
    return filename.split()[-1].split('.')[0]

# Ask the user if they want to see missing IDs
show_missing_IDs = ask_show_missing_IDs()

# Show missing IDs if the user wants it
if show_missing_IDs:
    missing_IDs_found = False
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".xlsx") and filename.startswith("FLIS"):
            output_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            missing_IDs = find_missing_IDs(output_path)
            if missing_IDs:
                if not missing_IDs_found:
                    print("Here are the missing IDs for each of the following dates:")
                    missing_IDs_found = True
                # Sort the IDs in alphabetical order before printing
                sorted_missing_IDs = sorted(missing_IDs)
                # Only print the date from the filename without "FLIS"
                print(f"{extract_date(filename)}:")
                for ID in sorted_missing_IDs:
                    print(ID)
                print()
    if not missing_IDs_found:
        print("No missing IDs found in any of the files.")

# Function to ask the user to delete the files
def ask_delete_files():
    while True:
        answer = input("Should the CSV and Excel files be automatically deleted? (Yes/No): ").strip().lower()
        print()
        if answer in ["yes", "no"]:
            return answer == "yes"
        else:
            print("Please answer with 'Yes' or 'No'.")

# Ask the user if they want to delete the files after processing
delete_files = ask_delete_files()

# Delete the files if the user wants it
if delete_files:
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith((".csv", ".xlsx")):
            os.remove(os.path.join(directory, filename))
    print("The files have been deleted.")
    print()

# Wait for user input before window closes
input("Press Enter to exit")

I have tried a variety of solutions from ChatGPT and Copilot, but nothing seems to work. Some of the solutions can sum the values and print it in the output, but I cannot get it to add the summed values, which I need for the comparison of files to pass.

You are using Pandas, you can make calculations with Pandas add to and write to to the Excel Sheet. You are using 'to_excel' to write to the Excel Sheet, so you can create a writer and use Xlsxwriter to write formulas (to calculate the rows) or (calculated) values to the Excel Sheet after the dataframe is written to the Sheet.

Try something like :
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
    worksheet = workbook[sheet_name]
for col in worksheet.iter_cols(min_row = 3, max_row = 4, min_col = 1, max_col = worksheet.max_column):
    sum_value = 0
    for cell in col:
        sum_value += cell.value
    wb_2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(second_file)
    worksheet_2 = workbook[sheet_name_2]
    cell_ = worksheet_2.cell(row = 4, column = col)
    cell_.value = sum_value
    worksheet_2.save(second_file)
worksheet.save(file_path)

From my understanding it should work. Keep in mind that you can switch the indexes in the loops (ex min_row) to match your expectations

I'm not sure but I think you can open wb_2 next to workbook. Tbc

Thanks for your reply - I didn't quite get it to work with this setup, but got some inspiration for another solution :-)
